# How to stop the media player on a service?

Tags: android

I have a media player inside a service which would play a beep at particular time for some seconds..

I want to stop it from a new activity that is launched from the service..Whether it is possible?

Whether I can reference the object for mediaplayer I have created and stop it?How to reference an object/variable from service?

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcast intent from the activity & have the service set up a receiver to listen for it.